# Why is this power residue symbol $=1$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am reading [this paper on Fermat's last theorem by **Stevenhagen** and **Lenstra**](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~hwl/PUBLICATIONS/1997b/art.pdf), and am confused with one statement. At line $4$ on page $502$, one finds the statement:

> *As $\left(\dfrac{x}{q}\right)$ is a galois invariant $p$-th root of unity, it equals $1$.*

And the assumptions:

> Here $q(\not=p)$ is a prime number dividing $y$, where $x^p+y^p+z^p=0$ and $\left(\dfrac{\cdot}{\cdot}\right)$ is the $p$-th power residue symbol for the cyclotomic field $\mathbb Q(\zeta_p)/\mathbb Q$.

And my question is: why is this true? I cannot see this statement clearly. I have tried to think of a reason this root of unity, applied by an automorphism on $\mathbb Q(\zeta_p)/\mathbb Q$, remains unchanged, but I could not even figure out what I shall get, after applying such an automorphism! I think this must be related to the expression $\left(\dfrac{x}{q}\right)=\left(\dfrac{x+\zeta_p y}{q}\right)$, but finds no apparent hints.
Any hints are mostly appreciated.

Comment: It remains to check this point, before I can understand the whole paper now...